# adding users to a user group in RHEL7

Tags: linux-kernel, rhel

***[root@thamizh thamizh]# groupadd -g examples example1
groupadd: invalid group ID 'examples'***

created group named examples and tired to add user example1 to it, but its giving error ***"invalid group ID examples"***, but examples group created by ***groupadd command***

Answer (score 0):

First, create a group:

```
groupadd example
```

Or, with specific GID:

```
groupadd -g 101 group1
```

After, add users to group:

```
usermod -g group1 user1
```

Or, add several groups for user using `-G` option:

```
usermod -G group1 group2 user1
```

Then check groups:

```
group user1
```